# How can I get the first and last name labels to align under the corresponding input forms?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, styles

How can I get the first and last name labels to align under the corresponding input forms? Can someone explain this logically? I think a lot of people would like to know this because of its aesthetics and professional look. The bulk of the CSS code is to perform css media queries. 
Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="css/book_now.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Danny4Help</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-m-12"></div>
        <div class="col-4 col-m-12">
            <div id="container">
                <h2>Book now</h2>
                <p>Get in touch with us</p>
                <ul>
                <li><p>Name</p>
                <input name="fname" size="8"> <input name="lname" size="14">
                <br><label>First</label><label>Last</label>
                </li>  
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-m-12"></div>
    </body>
```

CSS

```
     * {
    box-sizing: border-box;

    }
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
} 
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
#header{
    padding:15px;
    background-color:rgb(157,221,220);
    margin-bottom:7px;
}
body{
    background-color:white;
    color:rgb(164,111,67);
}
#container{
    font-size:12px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
label{
    padding:0px;
    clear:both;
}
```

This is what I want it to look like:
[image: x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocLaxukm/)

I have added a container div around your inputs and put respective labels in them.

adjust your css for the mobile screen.

```
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-group label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/dpL0u05e/)

I have wrapped each input field in a `<p>` tag with the class name `.inputs`. I have set this class to display `inline-block` so that the `<p>` tags sit inline with one another. Then just place `<br/>` tags between the `<input>` and the `<lable>` so that they are on separate lines.

HTML

```
      <p>Name</p>
      <p class="inputs">
        <input name="fname" size="8">
        <br/>
        <label>First</label>
      </p>
      <p class="inputs">
        <input name="lname" size="14">
        <br/>
        <label>Last</label>
      </p>
```

CSS

```
     .inputs {
       display: inline-block;
     }
```

Comment: this solution is also valid

Comment: I am glad that you have found a solution that you need

Comment: @fungusanthrax I will just note that my solution does not clip when the screen width is minimised. The accepted solution obscures the `<label>` named "First" when the screen width is minimised.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap the `input` and the `label` in another container. A `div` works fine for this solution, especially because it's being used to fix an aesthetic thing.

After wrapping the `input` and the `label` in a container, you must set the display of the container to `inline-block`, since you want both containers next to each other.

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/bbr47ucz/)